# Calculating the number of rows of text in a div on PHP server side

Tags: php, css, server-side

I came across to a weird problem that I am having a problem with. I have texts that I obtain from database with no character limit. What I am trying to achieve is that number of rows if that text put into a div width css property;

`width:600px`

Sounds weird but I need to manage this server side because I am going to arrange my style before they are printed on the page, so if the number of rows calculated on server side is less than 10 I will arrange something in a way, if it is more than 10 I will do another way. Any possible way to obtain this?

Comment: the amount of rows has also dependencies on the font type, font size and the letter spacing etc. of the text. So I won't follow this solution, since you've so many unknowns on clientside, so the amount of rows could not be exactly examined before delivering and rendering in the browser.

Comment: @Daxcode thanks for the heads up. Font-size: 14px, font-family:Arial.

Comment: @gosukiwi unfortunately. it has to be calculated before pushed to the client side.

Comment: @rolandbishop why do you've to know that before? If the user is increasing or decreasing the font size in his browser manually, the amount of rows would be changed again...

Comment: @Daxcode It would not matter after the initial calculation.

Comment: Then I'd suggest to get the text be rendered directly as an image, by using php's gd lib or imagemagick and deliver it as an image. Since it's the only way having the amount of rows examined roughly. And you'v more possibilities in getting the text pixelperfect. For accessible reasons, you should render the text on html as raw text and use css for having the image as a text alternate, so the content would be also readable without having the image in place (e.g. for screen readers, crawlers,...).

Comment: @Daxcode Silly idea but wanted to ask if it would work out. What if I simply create an empty page with a 600px width div inside and just and just count how much character it takes to fill an entire row, then divide the incoming text to this number and act according to this

Comment: @rolandbishop if the text won't contain any html formats like bold or links, this should work. Not sure how to deal with whitespaces etc... give it a try! :)

Comment: Daxcode is correct, this cannot be done on the server side as there are dependencies on settings that are rightly left to the user and only surface on the client side. Frankly, IMO, a design that is so fragile that it needs excessive trickiness like you're considering is a bad design.

Answer (score 1):

Check **[imagettfbbox()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php)** function. It calculates the width of string in pixel. First remove new lines from your text and than calcuate the whole text length, than divine into `600px`. You will obtain the row count.
  But this is not suggested way. Better try to use css or javascript for this

Comment: Thanks you for the quick response. I'm going to check it right now!

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this server side. There are enumerable client side settings and options that will affect this and a server side solution will never work properly in all cases. With JavaScript, it would be trivial to calculate the number of lines based on the rendered height divided by the line-height.

```
var lines = $('#somediv').height() / $('#somediv').css('line-height');
```